# $\Phi(A) = \max\{|\det(B)|\}$ show that $\Phi(A) = 0 \iff \text{rank}(A) \neq n$ where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $B \subset A$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $\Phi: \mathbb{R}^{m \times n} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}, \quad A \longrightarrow \max\{|\det(B)|\}$ where $B$ is a sub-matrix $n \times n$ of $A$.

I would like to show that $\Phi(A) = 0 \iff \text{rank}(A) \neq n$.

(i) $\Rightarrow$ :

If $\Phi(A) = 0$ then $\max\{|\det(B)|\} = 0$. Therefore, $\det(B) = 0$, $\forall B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$.

It means that there is no matrix $B$ of rank $n$. Therefore, rank$(A) \neq n$.

(ii) $\Leftarrow$ :

If rank$(A) \neq n$ then rank$(A) = l < n$. Therefore, $\exists$ a sub-matrix $B \in \mathbb{R}^{l \times l}$ such that $\det(B) \neq 0 \implies |\det(B)| > 0$.

Then, $\Phi(A) = \max\{|\det(B)|\} \geq 0$.

From there, I don't know how to go further ?

Answer (score 1):

You’ve got a “tall” matrix ($m \ge n$) presumably, otherwise there are no $n \times n$ submatrices.

We form $n \times n$ submatrices by “forgetting” $m - n$ rows of the matrix. This operation of “forgetting” rows itself can be represented by multiplication by a matrix on the right.

What is this matrix? Given a list of rows to forget, start with the $m \times m$ identity matrix, then forget those rows. For example, if you have a $5 \times 3$ matrix, and you want to form the $3 \times 3$ submatrix by forgetting the second and fifth rows, then your matrix would be

$$B = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}.$$

That is, if $A$ is $5 \times 3$, then $AB$ is the $3 \times 3$ submatrix consisting of the first, third and fourth rows.

How does this help? We have,
$$\operatorname{rank} AB \le \max\{\operatorname{rank} A, \operatorname{rank} B\} \le \operatorname{rank} A.$$
That is, the rank of any $n \times n$ submatrix is bounded above by the rank of $A$. If this is less than $n$, then the same is true for any $n \times n$ submatrix. Thus, all of their determinants would have to be $0$, in this case.

(The process of “forgetting” columns can analogously be represented by matrix multiplication on the left, though we don’t need it here. As such, any submatrix of $A$ can be written as a product $CAB$, for some matrices $B$ and $C$. Accordingly, the rank of any submatrix is less than or equal to the rank of the original matrix, by similar argument.)